# Having trouble Deserialize a jason of objects array

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

```json
{
    "-NL5BmYke6OAh580HEbF": {
        "Adress": "test",
        "ID": "test",
        "Namn": "test",
        "TelefonNummer": "test"
    },
    "-NL5Bncq0GgwLerFXS-v": {
        "Adress": "test1",
        "ID": "test1",
        "Namn": "test1",
        "TelefonNummer": "test1"
    }
}
```

This is the json but i have unique key numbers before the values i want to get and those are giving trouble accessing the json string inside.

`var strings = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(s);`

This is what im trying right now to get the invudual strings then too deserialize again but it doesnt work.

Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Note that a list of strings in JSON would look like `["a", "b", "c"]`. I'm sure you can see how very different your JSON is to that. Also, in 20203 you should probably be using System.Text.Json or JSON.NET, not JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Yes but the keys dont have a object reference so how do you reference them with a class?

Comment: I can't speak for JavaScriptSerializer, but with JSON.NET (and I think System.Text.Json) you can use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize your input as `Dictionary<string, Person>` (see the example below). The unique keys from your input will become keys in the result dictionary accessible via `deserialized.Keys`.

```cs
//define class that will serve as Type for values in your dictionary
public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Namn { get; set; }
    public string TelefonNummer { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}

//...

var json = "... your input here";

var deserialized = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Person>>(json);
```

You can then further iterate through the dictionary and set the Key as ID for example:

```cs
var persons = deserialized.Select(kvp =>
{
    var person = kvp.Value;
    person.ID = kvp.Key; // or add another property for this value
    return person;
});
```